# Automapper Config: Can I use .ForAllMembers when overriding CreateMap?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.CreateMap<ViewModel, Domain>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        //.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore()) //returns void
        .ReverseMap();
    }
 }

public class ViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
}

public class Domain 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    //public string ... { get; set;}  //etc..
    //...
}
```

Suppose I don't want to map `UserName`, and many other properties.

Can I do `.ForAllMembers(...)` to the mapping, in order to map any unmapped members?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that ForAllMembers thing, that looks like a version of this:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide#ignoreallnonexisting-extension

Instead, use the CreateMap overload that takes a MemberList enum:

```
CreateMap<ViewModel, Domain(MemberList.None)
```

Comment: I'm on version 4.2.1.0, but I see that his option exists in the most recent version.